# SharePoint Foundation, SQL Server Express & Forms Based Authentication

Tags: forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, sql

Are there any limitations to use SharePoint Foundation with a SQL Server Express and using Forms Based Authentication to log in?

Comment: It shouldnt be a problem. Here is a link to help you out:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/sharepoint2010setup/thread/587f75c4-162f-4e76-bea9-babd91701d36

Comment: Original link to the setup guide: http://blog.summitcloud.com/2009/11/forms-based-authentication-sharepoint-2010-fb/